# Proving theorems using the Compactness theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

We say an infinite set $S$ is closed under $\wedge$ if for all $a,b$  $\in S$ so $a\wedge b \in S$.

I need to prove that if S is closed under $\wedge$ and for all $a \in S$ we know is that $a$ is satisfied, **So $S$ is satisfied.**

I'm got confused about how to prove the question -

either by induction and showing that each finite subset of $S$ is satisfied or by direct proof using the fact that $S$ is closed under $\wedge$.

Comment: You want to use induction to show that $S$ is closed under finite conjunctions, then use that to show that $S$ is finitely satisfiable, and then apply the compactness theorem to conclude that $S$ is satisfiable.

Comment: "satisfied" is **not the same** as "satisfiable", so your question doesn't make sense...